# Test sensor hardware drivers with Gazebo and ROS

Tags: ros, hardware, ros-lunar, ros-kinetic, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to test ros sensor hardware driver but currently I don't have the hardware. Is it possible to test the hardware driver with gazebo.. If yes please share the steps for the same... I want to test sick lidar ros driver in gazebo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302351/test-sensor-hardware-drivers-with-gazebo-and-ros/) by [niti](https://answers.ros.org/users/37318/niti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I want to test ros sensor hardware driver but currently I don't have the hardware. Is it possible to test the hardware driver with gazebo

the idea is nice and it would be great if this was possible, but think about how that would work: ROS drivers typically interface with ROS on the one side, and with the hw on the other side.

Interfacing with the hw is either done directly (writing and readng registers in a specific memory area) or via some manufacturer provided library (or an intermediate form, but they're all similar enough to ignore the differences). In either case the *behaviour* of the hw (ie: responses to writing to certain registers or calling certain functions in the mfg's libraries) has to correspond to what is specified by the manufacturer, or any driver written would not work correctly.

Logically, this would mean that for Gazebo to be usable in such a situation it would have to simulate (to a certain degree) that behaviour, for *all* the devices that you'd like to test.

Possible: certainly. Feasible: for an open-source project with limited resources, I don't believe so.

Note that what you're asking about is known as a model-in-the-loop type of testing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1